# draw a Diagram in latex

Tags: diagrams

[image]

How would i produce the following diagram in latex which illustrates behavior of fish swarm search algorithm?

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `pgfplots`? (I'm assuming you have data you are plotting.)

Answer (score 2):

Use your own data instead of `rnd`:

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclareradialshading{rad}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}%
{color(0cm)=(blue!50!black);
color(0.15cm)=(blue);
color(0.35cm)=(blue!80);
color(0.7cm)=(green);
color(1cm)=(yellow);
color(1.2cm)=(red);
color(1.25cm)=(black)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits,
    ]
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,mark=*,domain=0:1] {rnd};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    %\path[opacity=0.8,shading=radial, inner color=blue,  outer color=red] (rel axis cs: 0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs: 1,1);
    \path[opacity=0.8,shading=rad] (rel axis cs: 0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs: 1,1);
    \end{scope}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]